# Spring Boot Application not registering @Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a simple SpringBoot application with spring-data-jpa for learning purposes.

My problem is when I try to @Autowire a @Repository the application always fails to start with the error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field pedidoRepository in com.pedidos.services.PedidoService required a bean of type 'com.pedidos.repositories.PedidoRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pedidos.repositories.PedidoRepository' in your configuration.
```

All the answers that i have found so far tells me to do something that is already done in my application. I'm probably missing something and I can't find out what it is.

This is how my application is now (imports are omitted):

### Application:

```
package com.pedidos;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PedidosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PedidosApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Repository:

```
package com.pedidos.repositories;

@Repository
public abstract class PedidoRepository implements JpaRepository<Pedido, UUID> {
}
```

### Service:

```
package com.pedidos.services;

@Service
public class PedidoService {

    @Autowired
    private PedidoRepository pedidoRepository;

    public Optional<Pedido> findById(UUID id){
        return pedidoRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Pedido save(Pedido pedido){
        return pedidoRepository.save(pedido);
    }

}
```

### Controller:

```
package com.pedidos.controllers;

@Controller("/pedido")
public class PedidoController {

    @Autowired
    private PedidoService pedidoService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Pedido get(@PathVariable(name = "id") UUID id){
        return pedidoService.findById(id).get();
    }

}
```

Here is my [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDqFC.png)

If do not inject the repository the application runs fine.

The entire code is in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/brunomokan/pedidos

Comment: Shouldn't this be `@Repository public interface PedidoRepository extends JpaRepository<Pedido, UUID>`?

Comment: Thank you @ILyaCyclone, that's exactly what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what ILya Cyclone say. A Spring-Data Repository should be an interface which get a proxy at runtime. Something like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/auditing/AuditableUserRepository.java). Its fine if you extend from another interface.